# No margin print with Epson TM-U220D

Tags: c#, printing, epson, printdocument, migradoc

I am using this Epson TM-U220D printer for printing receipts. By default, the margin is set to 1 inch on all four sides of paper.I do not find any options to edit it in the printer utility nor in any printer manual. I tried finding in Google. But no luck. Type of paper is Roll Paper (76 x 297 mm). Can anybody help me to adjust the margins?

Comment: How does this question relate to MigraDoc?

Comment: @ThomasH i m using migradoc to create the document, rendering it to pdf document and saving it. then printing the pdf doc using the default printer.

Comment: If the PDF file has correct borders, MigraDoc cannot be the problem and should not be listed as a tag.

Comment: @PankajSinaiNagarsekar YOu can also tag with your last meal - same relevance. THis is printing a PDF, MigraDoc is not involved, and we do not care what you had for breakfast either.

Comment: @ThomasH sir. i tried using all the print methods available. including itext sharp, printdoc in C# and all the methods available for printing.. I tagged migradoc only because i used it to print. i tried doin all the settings available in the printer, refered online printer manual and al the help available from google. The Page Scaling method is tried. No luck.

Comment: When I print PDF files using Adobe Reader with Page Scaling set to None in the Adobe Reader print options, then I get a printed page that is exactly like the page showing on the screen (allowing less then +/- 1 mm for mechanical tolerances of the paper feeder). If you still get an unwanted border using this method, the problem is with the printer driver or printer.

Answer (score 0):

When printing PDF files with Adobe Reader, make sure it prints at 100% (Page Scaling: None).

With the default settings, Adobe Reader will print the pages at 94% (for DIN A 4, may vary) and add an extra border around the pages.